# What is a "partial application install" via adb?

Tags: adb, installation

Android's `adb` has a *"partial application install"*:

```
$ adb install
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
...

  adb install [-lrtsd] <file>
  adb install-multiple [-lrtsdp] <file...>
                               - push this package file to the device and install it
                                 (-l: forward lock application)
                                 (-r: replace existing application)
                                 (-t: allow test packages)
                                 (-s: install application on sdcard)
                                 (-d: allow version code downgrade)
                                 (-p: partial application install)
```

Notice `-p` is *"partial application install"*.

What is a partial application install?

Answer (score 4):

It is my assumption that the *-p: partial application install* is for installing packages that are an update to an existing package but are not standalone in itself, sort of [how Play Store updates an app](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/105765/96277) using [delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_update) or smart updates.

`-p` requires a base package to exist and its name passed next to it, else it will throw the error

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing inherit package name
```

If the APK you're passing is not an incremental update to an existing package (`PACKAGE`), you would end up with

```
Failed to finalize session
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Missing existing base package for PACKAGE]
```

I do not have any incremental update so I can't verify my own claim, neither I have any other solid evidence for the whole claim other than these two:

A comment in [Issue:1134353002](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-reviews/9N5zlTX8sf4/E8zNaL5aHYgJ) thread

> Splits are not normal .apks, and they can only be installed via "adb install-multiple"

And, this code snippet mentioned under the source code of [PackageInstallerSession.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageInstallerSession.java#671)

```
else {
  // Partial installs must be consistent with existing install 
  final ApplicationInfo app = mPm.getApplicationInfo(mPackageName, 0, userId);
  if (app == null) {
      throw new PackageManagerException(INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK, "Missing existing base package for " + mPackageName);
  }
```

Comment: Briefly, this quote is enough: "adb install-multiple"