# adb install-multiple: Update to package <pkg> doesn't support multi arch

Tags: adb, installation, apk

I'm attempting to install [Chrome 100.0.4896.127-489612710](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-100-0-4896-127-release/google-chrome-fast-secure-100-0-4896-127-android-apk-download/) (arm-v7a, Android 6.0+) on a Pixel 3 running Android 9.  It's a .apkm file so I unzipped it and ran

```
adb install-multiple -r -d *.apk
```

However, I got the error message

> Failure: [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Update to package com.android.chrome doesn't support multi arch]

The relevant lines from `logcat` are

```
W PackageParser: Unknown element under <manifest>: uses-sdk at /data/app/vmdl286680564.tmp.split_extra_icu.apk Binary XML file line #3
W PackageParser: Unknown element under <manifest>: module at /data/app/vmdl286680564.tmp.split_extra_icu.apk Binary XML file line #5
W PackageParser: Update to package com.android.chrome doesn't support multi-arch
```

Comment: Seems like adb tries to install the APK files as update even if you specified `-r` (replace) argument. Or this happens because Chrome is installed as system app and thus if you try to install it, it is always an update installation. The only apps I know that could be named "multi-arch" are non-split APK files (single APK file installable via `adb install`).

Comment: I wonder if [-p (partial application install)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/111064/44325) will work in this case? Otherwise, you might need to check Chrome's version code to see the installed variant (the last 2 digits).

Comment: The currently installed version is 71.0.5378.99.  The versionCode is 357809952.

Comment: I think it's 71.0.3578.99 and [357809952](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-71-0-3578-99-release/google-chrome-fast-secure-71-0-3578-99-3-android-apk-download/) refers to (arm64-v8a + armeabi-v7a, Android 7.0+, nodpi) variant, the one with native 64-bit libs. Perhaps try the corresponding variant, [489612723](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-100-0-4896-127-release/google-chrome-fast-secure-100-0-4896-127-10-android-apk-download/)? Though, the original is a single APK, not a bundle...

Comment: @AndrewT., that successfully installed.  That's strange because `getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist` shows `arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi`.

Comment: Well, I guess that solves the issue, but I'm still not sure 100% about the cause, so anyone else is still free to investigate further and post an answer.

Answer (score -2):

apkm is just a split apk file distributed by apkmirror

apkpure has an equivalent called xapk

try to install using this command

```
adb install-multiple base.apk split_extra_icu.apk split_config.en.apk
```

Comment: As you can see from the question, that’s what I did.